# GRPC - nodejs DNS resolution failed

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go, grpc-node

I'm working with a GRPC service hosted with HTTPS and self-signed cert. When I connect using syntax like:

```
const client = new productService('https://grpc-server-xxx.com:9090',
grpc.credentials.createInsecure())
```

I am getting the error like this

```
{ Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed
at Object.exports.createStatusError (C:\grpc\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\grpc\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\grpc\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\grpc\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8) at callback (C:\grpc\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:847:24)code: 14,metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {}, flags: 0 },details: 'DNS resolution failed'
```

Anyone help me how can I resolve the issue.

Note: 
My OS is Windows 10,
nodejs -- v10.16.0,
GRPC

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The gRPC library does not recognize the `https://` scheme for addresses, so that target name will cause it to try to resolve the wrong name. You should instead use `grpc-server-xxx.com:9090` or `dns:grpc-server-xxx.com:9090` or `dns:///grpc-server-xxx.com:9090`. More detailed information about how gRPC interprets channel target names can be found in [this documentation page](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md).

Answer (score 0):

Noob mistake, but I did it.
Make sure your IP address is `0.0.0.0:9090` and not `0.0.0.0.9090`