# Why do GCR services cannot be reached via gRPC?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, nestjs, microservices, grpc

I have a simple microservice app using NestJS. It is intended for Google Cloud Run (GCR). In consists of:

- Gateway
- Microservice A

The Gateway is running like this:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>);
  const PORT = configService.get<number>('PORT');
  await app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App gateway is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
}
```

Microservices are handled by:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.registerAsync({
      clients: [
        {
          name: Microservice.CONTENT,
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: (config: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>) => {
            return {
              transport: Transport.GRPC,
              options: {
                url: config.get<string>('MS_CONTENT_URL'),
                package: CONTENT_PACKAGE_NAME,
                protoPath: join(PROTO_FOLDER_PATH, 'content.proto'),
              },
            };
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class MicroserviceClientModule {}
```

Microservice A inits as:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 5000;
  const logger = new Logger();

  const microserviceOptions: MicroserviceOptions = {
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      url: `0.0.0.0:${PORT}`,
      package: CONTENT_PACKAGE_NAME,
      protoPath: join(PROTO_FOLDER_PATH, 'content.proto'),
    },
  };
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    ContentModule,
    microserviceOptions,
  );
  await app.listen();
  logger.debug(`Started GRPC server on ${microserviceOptions.options.url}`);
}
```

The deployment to GCR happens with no problem. As the result, there is a GCR service for the gateway and a service for the microservice. After the first (initial) deployment creating a service, I manually set up the env vars for the services. Amongs the env vars, there is `MS_CONTENT_URL` which tells the Gateway where the microservice is running. in the local env, it is just, for example *localhost:5000*. But once it is deployed to GCR, it becomes something I do not understand. As I see it, I have to use the url given by GCR after the service deployment, such as `https://my-microservice-12345asbcdef-ey.a.run.app`. I tried both with and without `https`, `grpc` and `grpcs`: when I DO define the protocol, an attempt to reach the microservice via gateway leads to `14 UNAVAILABLE: Failed to parse DNS address dns:https:/my-microservice-12345asbcdef-ey.a.run.app`. Without protocol and no port, it is `1 CANCELLED: Call cancelled`.
If I enable the http/2 option, any request to the gateway fails with `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error`.

No VPC or anything like that was defined. Locally everything is working and with a similar request I do retrieve a simple JSON response. I also was thinking that I need to do something in the app code itself to somehow "activate" http/2 support.

All the project services have *Allow unauthenticated*.

***UPDATED***: When I make a gRPC call via Postman directly to the microservice, it works. But he porblem remains with a case when the call is done via the gateway to a microservice, or by a microservice to another microservice: it says *"1 CANCELLED: Call cancelled"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRPC - nodejs DNS resolution failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108070/grpc-nodejs-dns-resolution-failed)

Comment: @murgatroid99 Unfortunately that specific solution does not help. However, I found it myself: a line with `credentials: credentials.createSsl()` must be added. But anyway thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to others with the same problem to post an answer to this question describing the solution you found.